# How to grab draggable data and append to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, droppable

I am trying to drag the data with the class of `.draggable` and append it to another div. Right now I am using an alert to notify me when the file is dropped.

But how do I grab the data of each `draggable` content to be used in any of the draggable events?

Any help would be helpful

**example using text to append info** // http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/7psw1s4L/

Here is my jquery

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
        $('.draggable').on({

            dragstart: function() {
                $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
            },

            dragleave: function() {
                $(this).removeClass('over');
            },

            dragenter: function(e) {
                $(this).addClass('over');
                //e.preventDefault();
            },
            dragover: function(e) {
                //$(this).addClass('over');
                e.preventDefault();
            },

            dragend: function() {
                $(this).css('opacity', '1');
            },
            // 
            drop: function() {
               alert('drop');
               $(this).append(dataTransfer);
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you make a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: something like this but with the data of the draggable element @Mohamed-Yousef - http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/7psw1s4L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `html` (data) in a global variable. In `drop` you can use the `html` as you wish.

```js
var data = '';

jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
$('.draggable').on({
    // on commence le drag
    dragstart: function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
        data = $(this).html();
    },
    // on quitte l'élément concerné par le drag
    dragleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');
    },
    // on passe sur un élément draggable
    dragenter: function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('over');
        //e.preventDefault();
    },
    dragover: function(e) {
        //$(this).addClass('over');
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    // on lâche l'élément, le drag est terminé
    dragend: function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    },
    // 
    drop: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
       alert('drop');
       //$(this).append(dataTransfer);
      $(this).append(data);
    }
});
```

```css
/* Prevent the text contents of draggable elements from being selectable. */
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.draggable {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
}
.column header {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 0 1px;
  box-shadow: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
                               color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)),
                               color-stop(0.50, rgb(79,79,79)),
                               color-stop(1, rgb(21,21,21)));
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.column.over {
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns">
  <div class="draggable" draggable="true"><header>A lot of info</header></div>
  <div class="draggable" draggable="true"><header>Some info</header></div>
</div> 
<div class="draggable" draggable="true"><header>More info</header></div>
```

Comment: how can i have an if statement inside the function for example if i want to trigger something if that element has a class do something else like this i want to check if element has a class of `zip` if so show `.zip-code` when element is dropped - http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/7psw1s4L/1/ @Mosh Feu

Comment: `that element` the draggable element or the droppable?

Comment: i'm trying to select the draggable object - if the draggable object has the class of `zip` or what ever class i choose - i want it to run another function or in this instance `show` `.zip-code` @Mosh Feu

Comment: any suggestion? @Mosh Feu